# Is there any cleaner way to call a clouse property in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, closures

Consider this:

```
$x=new MyClass;
$x->y=function($name){return "Hi, $name";};
```

to call the closure I use `call_user_func($x->y,'Hasan')` that it's not so clean and convenient. Is there any better syntax? Perhaps similar to `$x->y("Hasan")` (which does not work.)

Comment: Maybe [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to ask if there is actually no problem

Comment: What specifically do you consider unclean or inconvenient about `call_user_func($x->y,'Hasan')`?

Comment: And perhaps you should consider Anonymous classes instead.... though that requires PHP7

Comment: Note that you can also set a new variable to point to $x->y which can be accessed as a function.... `$x=new stdClass;
$x->y=function($name){return "Hi, $name";};
$greetings = $x->y;

echo $greetings('Hasan');`

Comment: what if you use static function in class?

Comment: for example: 

    class MyClass{
    public static function y($name){echo "Hi, $name";} 
    }

    $x=new MyClass;
    $x::y('name');